# Docker container hardware resources utilization

Tags: docker

I am self learning docker, but while I am learning docker a question comes to my mind, I don't if this silly but really its a point for me.

My question is, suppose I have 4 CPUs and let say 16 GB RAM server, and I run a docker container, what is the amount of the underlying hardware will be utilized? and can I specify the amount of shared resources?

Thank you,

Comment: Forgot to check the [documentation?](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/#--memory-swap-details)?

Comment: actually yes :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, it can consume all the resources of machine (depending on how VM was configured). But you can provide limits on cpu and memory utilization by a container. Here is the official documentation on this https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/